# Manage errors while Linq query iteration

Tags: c#, linq

I have a Linq query as shown below

```
var ResultQuery = from Task in dtTasks.AsEnumerable()
                              select new { EmployeeName = Task.Field<string>("EmpName").Split(':')[1],
                                           EmployeeCode = Task.Field<string>("EmpName").Split(':')[0],
                                           ProjectId = Task.Field<string>("ProjectName").Split(':')[0],
                                           ProjectName = Task.Field<string>("ProjectName").Split(':')[1],
                                           TaskName = Task.Field<string>("TaskName"),
                                           TaskDescription = Task.Field<string>("TaskDescription"),
                                           StartDate = Task.Field<DateTime>("StartDate"),
                                           Duration = Task.Field<double>("Duration"),
                                           EndDate = Task.Field<DateTime>("EndDate"),
                                           LeadName = Task.Field<string>("LeadBy").Split(':')[1],
                                           LeadId = Task.Field<string>("LeadBy").Split(':')[0]
                              };

foreach (var task in ResultQuery)
            {

            }
```

`dtTasks` is an imported table from Microsoft Excel File. Since its a user input file there may be a lot of typos in it. In Linq Query how can I handle if any DateTime conversion failed, or object reference not set to instance error (the `String.Split` Method when blank or empty rows inserted)? I want to skip those iteration and give a warning to user about the reason to skip. How can I achieve this if I used Linq for this?

Comment: Did you tried using Task.Field<string>("EmpName").contains(":") ? Task.Field<string>("EmpName").Split(':')[1] : string.empty,

Comment: But how can I give a warning? Also when dateTime not convertible?

Comment: Are you only bothered about datetime If so then temporarily comment that datetime part of code and try the rest of the code. If that works properly then i will give you solution for the datetime.

Comment: Because the most important way to solve issues like these is only 1. Divide the problem to the extent you can. And once it is divided try solving each problem with the best possible way you can.

Comment: @NisargShah the excel file is filled by the user and it may contain errors. If so I want to warn the user about that and skip that particular line of entry

Comment: then why are you using this linq? dont you feel like using foreach loop?

Comment: Else try using where condition to check for the validity of data.

Comment: @NisargShah yes I felt so. I'm using for loop since I need to know the index when the casting or conversion failed. But I want to know whether its possible in Linq or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An enumerable is broken as soon as there is an exception - you cannot iterate further.

Following is a workaround:

```
var ResultQuery = dtTasks.AsEnumerable()
                  .Select(Task => {
                              try {  
                                  return new { EmployeeName = Task.Field<string>("EmpName").Split(':')[1],
                                           EmployeeCode = Task.Field<string>("EmpName").Split(':')[0],
                                           ProjectId = Task.Field<string>("ProjectName").Split(':')[0],
                                           ProjectName = Task.Field<string>("ProjectName").Split(':')[1],
                                           TaskName = Task.Field<string>("TaskName"),
                                           TaskDescription = Task.Field<string>("TaskDescription"),
                                           StartDate = Task.Field<DateTime>("StartDate"),
                                           Duration = Task.Field<double>("Duration"),
                                           EndDate = Task.Field<DateTime>("EndDate"),
                                           LeadName = Task.Field<string>("LeadBy").Split(':')[1],
                                           LeadId = Task.Field<string>("LeadBy").Split(':')[0]
                                  }
                               } catch(Exception e) {
                                        Console.WriteLine("Print your warning!");
                                        return null;
                               }
                  });



foreach (var task in ResultQuery)
{
   if(task != null) {
        // do your processing
   }
}
```